# How to disable responsive layout in Bootstrap 3 on small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter

Is it possible to disable responsive layout in Bootstrap 3 on small devices?

For example on devices smaller than 1000px display horizontal scroll and stop resizing elements.

Comment: This should help you: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Comment: But i need to disable it only on small devices. For example smaller than 100px. How to use it in that case?

Comment: Would taking out their `@media` queries and putting your own with your own code not work?